# Exibir imagens em "Galeria" com Python (Tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

Olá, a  ideia é selecionar todas as imagens de um diretório (pasta), ele exibiria todas essas imagens em miniatura numa JANELA via TKINTER (Python).

Consegui localizar todos os diretórios das imagens com o WHILE, como no código abaixo, mas não consigo fazer com que todas exibam automaticamente.

Teria alguma biblioteca ou função nativa para criar essa "galeria" de imagens?

```js
from tkinter import *
from typing import Sized
from PIL import *
import os
import cv2

class Window(Frame):
    

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        
        load = Image.open("temporario/page0.png")
        load.thumbnail((350,350))
        render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)
        
        img = Label(self, image=render)
        img.image = render
        img.place(x=50, y=50) 


        files = []
        pasta = 'temporario'
        for (diretorio, subpastas, arquivos) in os.walk(pasta):
            files.extend(arquivos)
        #print(pasta + '/' + files[2])
        
        
        i = 0
        while i <= 2:
            
            ronaldo = 0
            dirImg = pasta + '/' + files[i]
            loading = Image.open(dirImg)
            loading.thumbnail((350,350))
            renderiza = ImageTk.PhotoImage(loading)            
            
            i = i + 1
            print(dirImg)
            imagemA = Label(self, image=renderiza)
            imagemA.image = renderiza
            imagemA.place(x=350, y=50)

            
root = Tk()
app = Window(root)
root.wm_title("Tkinter window")
root.geometry("800x500")
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá, eu não rodei o seu código, mas o meu palpite é que você não consegue colocar todas as imagens porque o tkinter perde a referência dessas imagens cada vez que você cria uma imagem nova. Lembre-se que o tkinter está rodando em um loop contínuo e ele precisa sempre checar qual imagem ele precisa mostrar. Se você muda o valor de renderiza, ele já não tem mais a referência para aquela imagem. Uma alternativa é você criar um vetor para a variável renderiza:

```
    renderiza = []
    i = 0
    while i <= 2:

        ronaldo = 0
        dirImg = pasta + '/' + files[i]
        loading = Image.open(dirImg)
        loading.thumbnail((350,350))
        renderiza.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(loading))
        
        print(dirImg)
        imagemA = Label(self, image=renderiza[i])
        # imagemA.image = renderiza[i]
        imagemA.place(x=350, y=50)
        i = i + 1
```